# R Error: Multi-argument returns are not permitted, but there is no multi-argument

Tags: r, function, dataframe

So I was tasked with helping my PI at my research lab come up with a simple function to help choose two random values from a dataframe whilst ignoring NA's. The data we work worth is based on self-report data so we have some areas left unanswered and we get NA's. We don't drop our NA's but during analysis for subscales we do need to select some values while ignoring NA's.

I have a simple test dataframe made and began working on my test function. I know it won't work as I need it to but I am running into a weird error. Here is my code.

```
rm(list = ls())                   ### clear all ###
dev.off(dev.list()["RStudioGD"])
options(scipen=999)

install.package("dplylr")
install.package("magrittr")
library("magrittr")
library("dplyr")

df<- data.frame("Var1"=c(1,7,8), "Var2"=c(NA, NA, 9), "Var3"=c(2, NA,10), "Var4"=c(3,5,NA), "Var5"=c(4,7,NA))

#select columns funciton, picks two random values from data frame not containing NA
select.col <- function(x,y) ##given df x select y columns
  df %>% 
    select_if(is.numeric) %>%
    return(z)

b <- select.col(df,2)
```

so, I'm trying to make a function which selects the second parameter as a random column from each row where NA is not selected.

I would want b to be a new data set and consist of these data in this format:

```
1, 2
2, 7
3, 9
```

(basically my data selected randomly without NA's...kind of like elementary x,y/input-output tables)

I ran into this snag and no matter how I rewrite this function I get the same error of "Multi-argument returns are not permitted."

Any ideas or advice?

EDIT: I fixed the formatting for how I want my data to look. Imagine it like a CSV; so in one column is one value and in another is the other value.

Comment: What is z?  I think that you just want `%>% return()`

Comment: perfect. That fixed this initial issue.

Comment: Oh sorry, formatting is wrong. I'll fix it in an edit now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

```
select.col <- function(x,y) {
   nc <- y
   nr <- nrow(df)

   df %>%
     #select only numeric columns
     select_if(is.numeric) %>%
     #Convert data into a vector
     unlist %>%
     #Remove NA values
     na.omit %>%
     Select random nc * nr values
     sample(nc * nr) %>%
     #Convert it into matrix specifying number of rows and columns
     matrix(ncol = nc, nrow = nr) %>%
     #Convert into dataframe
     as.data.frame()
} 

select.col(df,2)

#  V1 V2
#1  5  1
#2  3 10
#3  8  2
```

Comment: Whoa yeah I wasn't expecting an answer that in-depth and complete. What exactly does the function do in each step? Is it turning the dataframe into a matrix and then excludes the NA's? When I was writing my own yesterday I was toying around with that but it looked a lot messier than this. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @AlexSmith I added some explanation as comments in the answer.

Comment: Thanks much! In a script I was writing (didn't post it on here) I tried to use na.omit myself but neglected to convert my data to a vector. Using na.omit just basically "cleared" the data from the dataframe and it said there were no values. Am I correct in understanding that NAs couldn't be removed when the data was listed in a dataframe?

Comment: Yes, `na.omit` remove the entire row when in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
df %>% 
select_if(is.numeric) %>%
return(z)
```

It is the same as

```
return(select_if(df, is.numeric), z)
```

`return` does not take two arguments, which is why you get the error message. Also, note that your return statement uses z, but z is not defined anywhere.